# React filtering the state without ruining it

Tags: reactjs

Im trying to make a search function that renders the name of the people that is matched in a search text input.

The problem is that I set the state to the items that match the search, and then the initial state is lost so no more searching can be done since the state will be empty. So how do I "fill up" the state each time?

Or maybe there is some other way without actually setting the state that im not aware of.

I tried to fix this with an attempt to reset to initial state when the handleSearch function is called right before the filter but that doesnt work.

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from './Header';
import peopleData from '../persons.json';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.handleSearch = this.handleSearch.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      people: peopleData
    }
  }

  handleSearch(wordToMatch){
    this.setState({ people: peopleData }); //Attempt to reset to initial state
    const result = this.state.people.filter(d => {
      const regex = new RegExp(wordToMatch, 'gi');
      return d.Name.match(regex);
    });
    this.setState({ people: result })
  }

  render() {
    const list = this.state.people.map((d, i) => <li key={i}>{d.Name}</li>);
    return (
      <div className="myApp">
        <Header
          tagline={"testing"}
          handleSearch={this.handleSearch}
        />
        <ul className="contentBody">
          {list}
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Component with the search input:

```
import React from 'react';

class Header extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <header>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder={this.props.tagline}
          ref={(input) => this.searchInput = input}
          onChange={() => this.props.handleSearch(this.searchInput.value)}
        >
        </input>
      </header>
    )
  }
}

export default Header;
```

How my data looks like

```
[
  {
    "Name": "Adam",
    "Born": 1971
  },

  {
    "Name": "Bob",
    "Born": 1999
  },
etc etc for 20 more names
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setState function won't immediately update the state object. So when you reference `this.state.people`, it will reference the state prior to the `setState` call. You can update your code to:

```
handleSearch(wordToMatch) {
    const result = peopleData.filter(d => {
        const regex = new RegExp(wordToMatch, 'gi');
        return d.Name.match(regex);
    });
    this.setState({
        people: result
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the `handleSearch` set the state for the `searchString` variable. Then in the render method, instead of simply mapping the state, you first filter the people list, and that result is what you map.

Change:

```
const list = this.state.people.map((d, i) => <li key={i}>{d.Name}</li>);
```

into this:

```
const list = this.state.people.filter(d => {
  const regex = new RegExp(this.state.searchString, 'gi');
  return d.Name.match(regex);
}).map((d, i) => <li key={i}>{d.Name}</li>);
```

This way, the list in the state is left unaltered, and you filter when rendering.